# ubuntu kernel, INT 13H interrupt, filesystem writing

Tags: kernel, interrupt

I use ubuntu and the grub 2 boot loader.

The question is:

I'd like to know if the Ubuntu kernel uses `BIOS/UEFI` services, in particular the `INT 13H` interrupt, or if the kernel is BIOS independent ?

In this last case in which a way Ubuntu treats the low-level disk services ? That is in which way Ubuntu intercept the call and passes it to the operating system's native disk I/O mechanism bypassing BIOS routines for the low-level disk reading/writing access ?

My understanding is that the Linux kernel typically doesn't use BIOS services for disk I/O since it's running in protected mode. However I don't know if could be there some edge cases where this isn't true and could happen that the kernel executes writing operations into the filesystem of the plugged disk.

So I thought to ask for tips about this topic.

Comment: SO is not an "Ubuntu mailing list", but welcome anyway. Maybe you confound with https://askubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: Hi ! Thanks ! I apologize with you. However i used askubuntu.com, but they addressed me here about the question i posed. Tips are welcome about where i can ask about the ubuntu kernel developers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fare enough, you'll probably find some kernel developpers here.